# having trouble for making a linked list in fortran

Tags: fortran

I have a question about creating a linked list in `FORTRAN`.  I hope some one has some ideas for me!
I want to create a list which contain some nodes and every node has one function.
Is it possible to do this or not? And can I use linked list for this purpose?

```
TYPE NODE
     INTEGER                 :: handle
     DOUBLE PRECISION, FUNCTION      :: A
     TYPE(NODE) , POINTER    :: NEXT
END TYPE NOD
```

Comment: To store different functions inside your user-defined type, you probably want procedure/function pointers.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612466/how-to-alias-a-function-name-in-fortran for an example.

Comment: This is a great pdf about making a linked list in Fortran http://www.iag.uni-stuttgart.de/IAG/institut/abteilungen/numerik/images/4/4c/Pointer_Introduction.pdf