# Using fortran to pass functions into a subroutine.

Tags: function, fortran, subroutine

I've written a set of subroutines and compiled them into a library. These subroutines are based on some defined function(x,y). At the moment this is buried inside the library routine - however what I'd like is to be able to pass any function(x,y) into this library - is this possible? Thanks guys!

Comment: Yes, pass a procedure / function pointer.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612466/how-to-alias-a-function-name-in-fortran

Answer (score 1):

```
module ExampleFuncs

   implicit none

abstract interface
   function func (z)
      real :: func
      real, intent (in) :: z
   end function func
end interface


contains


subroutine EvalFunc (aFunc_ptr, x)

   procedure (func), pointer :: aFunc_ptr
   real, intent (in) :: x

   write (*, *)  "answer:", aFunc_ptr (x)

end subroutine EvalFunc


function f1 (x)
  real :: f1
  real, intent (in) :: x

  f1 = 2.0 * x

end function f1


function f2 (x)
   real :: f2
   real, intent (in) :: x

   f2 = 3.0 * x**2

end function f2

end module ExampleFuncs


program Func_to_Sub

   use ExampleFuncs

   implicit none

   procedure (func), pointer :: f_ptr => null ()

   f_ptr => f1
   call EvalFunc (f_ptr, 2.0)

   f_ptr => f2
   call EvalFunc (f_ptr, 2.0)

   stop

end program Func_to_Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't need to be done with a pointer. You can pass a procedure name directly when the corresponding dummy argument is declared with a consistent interface. But pointers work too.

Comment: This can be done also without abstract interface, just in declaring EXTERNAL the argument corresponding to the function (as far as I remember, passing a procedure by argument is a very old Fortran feature, already available in F66 for instance). Of course, the asbtract interface (F2003) is a safer solution which avoid to pass a wrong procedure to EvalFunc.

Comment: Thanks guys. So in the example above can the functions f1 and f2 be defined in the program? I.e if the module ExampleFuncs was a library/blackbox as far as the user is concerned they could define the function either in the program or a separate module? and call ExampleFuncs. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure.  Edit the example and try it out.  Just have the abstract interface of the function in a module `use`d so that you can use it to declare the functions.