# The name of a subroutine can be a variable in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, subroutine

I was wondering if there is something similar to this in Fortran. Of course this example does not compile but I think you can get the idea.

```
program test
    character(1):: sub

    sub='A'
    call sub

    sub='B'
    call sub
end program

subroutine A
    print*,'OK! A'
end subroutine A

subroutine B
    print*,'OK! B'
end subroutine B
```

Comment: If it doesn't compile then it seems it mustn't work.  Aren't you answering your own question?

Comment: Are you asking "**Can** the name of a subroutine be a variable in FORTRAN?"  If not, please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Please read "[ask]" for additional tips on how to ask a question.

Comment: You can't do calling based on subroutine names, but you can use procedure pointers instead: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612466/how-to-alias-a-function-name-in-fortran/8612679.  How useful that question is really depends on exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot accomplish this by setting a character variable, but you can do this with procedure pointers.  I've modified your example slightly to implement that.  See:

```
program test
 implicit none

 abstract interface
    subroutine no_args
    end subroutine
 end interface

 procedure(no_args), pointer :: sub => null()

 sub => A
 call sub

 sub => B
 call sub

contains

subroutine A
 implicit none
 print *,"OK! A"
end subroutine

subroutine B
 implicit none
 print *,"OK! B"
end subroutine

end program
```

The changes are:

- Define an interface for the procedure pointer
- Declare `sub` as a procedure pointer to that abstract interface

You can then assign `sub` to subroutines that take no arguments (since that is the what the interface says) and call them through `sub` the way you envision.

Answer (score 0):

Closest you could get is function/procedure pointers, but that would be fortran-2003. BAsically, given input 'A' or 'B' you set pointer to point to either `subroutine A` or `subroutine B`. More details at [How to alias a function name in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612466/how-to-alias-a-function-name-in-fortran/8612679)