# How to store a set of functions into a Fortran array

Tags: arrays, function, fortran, names

As we know that function name can be treated as parameters to pass in/out by other subroutines. I wonder if we have any tricks to save a list of functions into an array, which would be passed in and out for process.

!-------for example.
At somewhere we set any array

```
type(Idonotknow)::Farray(N)
```

Then set the value:

```
Farray(1)%any=>fun1

Farray(2)%any=>fun2

...
Farray(N)%any=>funN
```

where fun1,fun2...funN are something like

```
Function fun1(input)
         implicit none
         statements 
End Function
```

Finally we can call them

```
do i = 1, N
  Call F(i)%any(input)
enddo
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit.(example)

Comment: This is the concept of function pointers.

Comment: seems so. I have found something at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612466/how-to-alias-a-function-name-in-fortran. This is helpful. But I wonder how to declare an array and save a set of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should create a type that contain only a procedure pointer that doesn't pass any argument. and then create an array of that type.

Example:

```
program test_func_array
   implicit none

   type pp
    procedure(func) ,pointer ,nopass :: f =>null()
   end type pp

   interface
      function func(x)
         real :: func
         real, intent (in) :: x
      end function func
   end interface

   type(pp) :: func_array(4)

   func_array(1)%f => exp
   func_array(2)%f => tan
   func_array(3)%f => cos
   func_array(4)%f => sin

   print*,func_array(1)%f(1.)
   print*,func_array(2)%f(1.)
   print*,func_array(3)%f(0.)
   print*,func_array(4)%f(0.)  

end program test_func_array
```

Comment: Note that you need a F2003 conformant compiler.  The ones that only accept F95 syntax will not be able to build it.

Comment: That is it. Thanks so much.