# Is there any way to call Fortran subroutine from character variable (which holds name of subroutine) instead of name of actual subroutine

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have a Fortran subroutine `Sample`. I call it inside another program. I am looking for a way to call it with a character variable, not like `call sample()` but like the following

```
Program calculate
  character(97) :: ii='Sample'
  call ii() ! So it call Sample subroutine
End program

Subroutine Sample
  print 'something'
End Subroutine Sample
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to alias a function name in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612466/how-to-alias-a-function-name-in-fortran)

Comment: Procedure pointers or just `select case()`. Not sure if exact duplicate. (I had to reopen some recently so I am more careful.)

Comment: thanks dear. I found a solution after your guide.   

`module test  
 contains  
    subroutine test1(argi,hello)  
    integer :: argi  
    external :: shabi  
    arg=5  
    call hello(argi)  
    end subroutine test1  
  
    subroutine test2(argg)  
    integer :: argg  
    print*,'value through test1 to test2:', argg  
    end subroutine test2  
  
end module test



program test_func_ptrs  
use test
implicit none <br/>
 call test1(5,test2)  

end program test_func_ptrs`

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer